# Function that randomizes a string (permutation) in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, char, permutation

Is there a way to code a function that gets a string for example "Overflow!" and returns a random Permutation with the first, last and penultimate char staying the same?

Examples of the randomized string could be "Orfevolw!" or "Oervolfw!".

Thank you.

Comment: Please may you show us your efforts as a [mcve]? Sadly, StackOverflow is not a place to present a code challenge and ask for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Use string.randomize function ( I created this function returns randomly arranged string) on string variable

```
 String.prototype.randomize = function() {
    let str = "";
    let array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      array.push(this[i])
    }
    array.sort(() =>  0.5 - Math.random());
    array.forEach(word => {
      str += word
    })
    return str;
  }

  let str = "Overflow";
 // Calling .randomzie function 
  str = str.randomize()
// Logging it 
  console.log(str)
```

Comment: @buchfrau Does this answer solves your problem ?

Comment: Although the answer is good, please reconsider answering such low-effort questions?

Comment: @buchfrau  Hey man it's been days is your problem solved ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `string` and the `constants` number array that you don't want to change.

```js
const generateString = (str, constants = []) => {
  const strArray = str.split("");
  const result = Array(str.length)
    .fill("")
    .map((s, i) => {
      if (constants.includes(i))
        return strArray.splice(i - (str.length - strArray.length), 1);
      return "";
    });

  for (let i = 0; i < result.length; ++i) {
    if (!result[i]) {
      const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * strArray.length);
      result[i] = strArray.splice(random, 1);
    }
  }
  return result.join("");
};

console.log(generateString("Overflow!", [0, 7, 8]));
console.log(generateString("Overflow!"));
```

Comment: Although the answer is good, please reconsider answering such low-effort questions?